# Increasing the storage of an existing SQL Server RDS instance on AWS

Tags: sql-server-2014, amazon-rds

Is there a way to increase the storage capacity of an existing SQL Server RDS instance on AWS ?

AWS documentation says it can't be as per https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-out-of-storage/

What are other alternatives to achieve this ? How are people dealing with this situation in real time like in the case of production scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to increase the storage for SQL Server Database on Amazon RDS.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ModifyInstance.SQLServer.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-out-of-storage/

The only option is to Create a new RDS instance with more size and migrate all the data/databases

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html

This really really sucks and defy the meaning of cloud, i really dont have any idea how the whole world is handlin this scenario especially in production environments where data grows rapidly. Also the Amazon DMS service for Data Migartion is not useful at all as it does not transfer the Identity columns, foreign keys/secondary keys/Indexes and Stored Procedures/Functions/Triggers.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the volume size of a running instance from the Modify DB Instance page.

1. Go to Instances;
2. Select your instance and choose 'Modify' from the 'Instance Actions' dropdown;
3. Locate the 'Allocated Storage' TextBox
4. Change the value and click 'Continue'

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ModifyInstance.SQLServer.html

Comment: This answer is 2 years newer than the accepted answer, and it seems AWS does allow this now... Especially today in 2023 (I just did it). I believe this is the correct answer now. Don't pass this one up!

Answer (score 1):

You can take snapshot of the current RDS and spawn a new RDS with more storage and this snapshot id.

Not sure how to do this from AWS-cli, but using cloudformation, you can create a new RDS instance from snapshot and give it more size. 
See the below links

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-dbsnapshotidentifier

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-allocatedstorage

Comment: Thank you for the solution, Have you tried this before ? this is the first time i saw something saying its possible. Can you give more details like how to setup this Cloudfront stuff to quickly start and test this approach ?

Comment: We have tried this before (almost 8 months ago). We are using cloudFormation (not Cloudfront)
You can test this setup with a fairly small RDS. Using below steps:
1. Create RDS and insert dummy data. Give it less space (2GB)
2. Take snapshot of this RDS.
3. Create another RDS using cloudformation and the snapshot. Give it more size.

Comment: Actually i tried it with {
    "Resources" : {
        "MyDB" : {
            "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
            "Properties": {       
                "DBInstanceClass"       : "db.t2.medium",
                "AllocatedStorage"      : "400",
                "MasterUsername"        : "xxxxxxx",
                "MasterUserPassword"    : "xxxxx",
                "DBSnapshotIdentifier"  : "xxxxxxxx-2016-07-13-17-00",
    "Iops":"2000",
    "StorageType":"io1"
            }
        }
    }
} and it did create new instance but only of 200gb as my previous snapshot

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=399287 , It doesn't work for sql server. The exact error is "AllocatedStorage cannot be modified for DB Instances with this engine: sqlserver-se". For that matter it doesn't even work for sqlserver-ee, sqlserver-web or sqlserver-express, anything