# SQL Server RDS SSD Upgrade over 200GiB

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to upgrade my database server SSD from 200GB to 1TB mainly because of the IOPS benefit you get but the Modify section has the GB option locked. The server is running SQL Server on r5.large

I have tried taking a snapshot for the server and starting another one but the new server did not give me the option of SSD storage and I really don't need/want to pay for provisioned IOPS at this point.

I've read a few posts in here with the same issue but nobody provided a solid example so far.

Is it possible to use an external tool to migrate the data from one database to another?
Did anyone use DMS on AWS? How was the experience? It looks a bit more complicated than it should it from a first glance.

-Update- 
Here is what I get when I try to modify the instance

[image]

Comment: Did you try `1024 GB`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The option for storage size is completely grayed out and the Min and Max values are 200GiB

Comment: @Geo this doesn't look like a programming question. Did you contact AWS support? Check the docs? You won't find examples for things like that : it's either a UI problem, something only Support can do, or something that's simply NOT available for your subscription/service type. Which you didn't mention.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No on the support. I saw this question a number of times in here with different answers on them so I thought to try one more time. The product documentation states that gp2 or io1 should be eligible for the update but older instances are not.

Comment: @Geo again, SO isn't Amazon support. You just mentioned that your instance may not be eligible for update. We don't know what your instance is. You get different answers because service offerings change over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Amazon RDS for SQL Server Supports Scaling Storage Size](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-rds-for-sql-server-supports-scaling-storage-size/):

> Posted On: Nov 22, 2017
>
> You can now scale the storage of your Amazon RDS for SQL Server database instances up to 16TB. An instance must use the Provisioned IOPS or General Purpose (SSD) storage types to be eligible. **Some instances with older storage configurations are not eligible.**

Your RDS instance might be one of these "older" ones.

See also: [aws rds - Increasing the storage of an existing SQL Server RDS instance on AWS - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331599/increasing-the-storage-of-an-existing-sql-server-rds-instance-on-aws)

Comment: Thank John I must have missed this one. I will delete this post to avoid duplicate content.